# Search in custom table - React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to make a table with api data searchable. I'm on my way, but unsure on how to proceed further.

Code looks like this:

```
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
    const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
    
    const handleChange = event => {
        setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const results = apiData.filter(person => 
            person.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
        );
        setSearchResults(results);
    }, [searchTerm]);

    const renderPerson = (contact, index) => {
        return (
            <tr key={index}>
                <td>{contact.ID}</td>
                <td>{contact.Info.Name}</td>
                <td>{contact.InfoID}</td>
                <td>{contact.Info.DefaultEmail.EmailAddress}</td>
                <td>{contact.Info.DefaultPhone.Number}</td>
                <td>{contact.Info.InvoiceAddress.AddressLine1}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    }

 return (
        <Fragment>
            <input type="text" value={searchTerm} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Søk.."></input>
            <table id="myTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr className="header">
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Navn</th>
                        <th>Info Id</th>
                        <th>E-post</th>
                        <th>Telefon</th>
                        <th>Adresse</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {apiData.map(renderPerson)}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </Fragment>
    )
```

https://dev.to/asimdahall/simple-search-form-in-react-using-hooks-42pg
I've followed this guide, but since I have the renderPerson function, I'm a bit unsure on how to handle this.

Question: Is there any way to get this working, or am I approaching it the wrong way? I'm aware that I need to put searchResult in the tbody somehow, but then the table won't be populated.

Any help is much appreciated

Edit: displaying code for getting apiData:

```
useEffect(() => {
        getContacts()
    }, [])

    const getContacts = () => {
        $.ajax({
            url: `http://localhost:5000/getContacts`,
            type: "POST",
            data: ajaxObj,
            success: (data) => {
                let response = JSON.parse(data)
                setApiData(response)
                
                setLoading(false)
            },
            error: () => {
                console.log("noe feilet?");
            }
        });
    }
    console.log(apiData)
```

Data looks like this:

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8GjB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `apiData` to `searchResults` on render

```
<tbody>
   {searchResults.map(renderPerson)}
</tbody>
```

Change your filter way result (Updated)

```
const results = apiData.filter(person => 
   person.Info.Name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
);

....

const renderPerson = (item, index) => {
        return (
            <tr key={index}>
                <td>{item.ID}</td>
                <td>{item.Info.Name}</td>
                <td>{item.InfoID}</td>
                <td>{item.Info.DefaultEmail.EmailAddress}</td>
                <td>{item.Info.DefaultPhone.Number}</td>
                <td>{item.Info.InvoiceAddress.AddressLine1}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've allready tried this, and as I stated in my question, the table wont be populated when I try that.  Also, when I try to write anything in the search box, it crashed, giving: TypeError: person.toLowerCase is not a function.

Comment: what is `apiData` in your component? where it defines ?

Comment: @JohnnyFoxville I have updated my answer please check

Comment: Thanks again for the response. The search is now functional, but the table wont populate before I have done a search first. Any ideas to fixing this?

Comment: I had updated my answer and added `person.Info.Name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)` you still getting crash? The table will populate when it has searched data

Comment: Its not crashing now no, but I would like the table to be populated before a search is made..?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
export default function () {
 
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);

const apiData=[
        {
            ID:'1222',
            Info:{
                ID:'1222',
                EmailAddress:'test@test.com',
                Number:'2222222222',
                AddressLine1:'test'
            }
        },
        {
            ID:'2333',
            Info:{
                ID:'2333',
                EmailAddress:'test2@test.com',
                Number:'1111111111',
                AddressLine1:'test2'
            }
        }
    ]
    
    const handleChange = event => {
        setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
        if(event.target.value){
            const results = apiData.filter(person => 
                person.ID.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value)
            );
            setSearchResults(results);
        }else{
            setSearchResults([]);
        }
        
    };


    const renderPerson = (contact, index) => {
        return (
            <tr key={index}>
                <td>{contact.ID}</td>
                <td>{contact.Info.Name}</td>
                <td>{contact.Info.ID}</td>
                <td>{contact.Info.EmailAddress}</td>
                <td>{contact.Info.Number}</td>
                <td>{contact.Info.AddressLine1}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    }

 return (
        <Fragment>
            <input type="text" value={searchTerm} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Søk.."></input>
            <table id="myTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr className="header">
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Navn</th>
                        <th>Info Id</th>
                        <th>E-post</th>
                        <th>Telefon</th>
                        <th>Adresse</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {searchResults.map(renderPerson)}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </Fragment>
    )

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This also makes the search function work. However the same issue regarding that the table is empty before anything is entered in the search box. Also it would be nice to be able to search for more than just name / id, but all of them.